# Stored Procedure with SQL Server and Laravel

Tags: sql-server, laravel

so I have a stored procedure with parameter, the parameter is no_skbdn which i can get from the $skbdn

```
$skbdn = DB::select('SELECT no_skbdn FROM selectSKBDN');
$nama = DB::select('EXEC selectNameInSO :no_skbdn', $skbdn);
return view('layouts.form_so', ['skbdn' => $skbdn, 'nama' => $nama]);
```

but when i ran this code, all i get is an error

> Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Comment: Are you  sure that the first query retrun a signle value?

Comment: @Dordi actually actually it isn't. do you know how can i get that no_skbdn but with only single value?

Comment: You can add `TOP (1)` in your first query, it will give you the first value it sees, your query would be `SELECT TOP (1) no_skbdn FROM selectSKBDN`